# Ruby install for a user is different from sudo?

Tags: ruby, installation, version, sudo

I need to have at least version 1.9 installed in the system. However, when I run `ruby -v` in "normal mode" and "sudo mode", they are different:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
$ sudo ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

If I do `which ruby`:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ sudo which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

How do I install Ruby so that it's the same for both of them?

Comment: You add `/usr/local/bin` to the front of root's PATH. Really though, root should not have `/usr/local/bin` in its path in case something goes wrong. Root isn't a "user" it's for administration of the system. If root needs to run something using /usr/local/bin/ruby, then add that explicitly to the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short you can place path /usr/local/bin/ruby for superuser **before** /usr/bin/ruby.

$sudo echo $PATH

will show you current state of art